# How do I handle errors with promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, promise, bluebird

As a node programmer. I'm used to use "nodebacks" for handling errors in my code:

```
myFn(param, function(err, data) {
    if (err){
        //error handling logic
     }
     else {
        // business logic
    }
});
```

When writing that function, I can do something like:

```
var myFn = function(param, callback){
    var calc = doSomeCalculation(param);
    if(calc === null) { // or some other way to detect error
        callback(new Error("error with calculation"), null);
    }
    ...
    someAsyncOp(calcN,function(err, finalResult){
        if(err) return callback(err, null);
        callback(null, finalResult); // the error is null to signal no error
    });

};
```

How would I do this sort of error handling with promises?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

#### Rule of Thumb

Whenever you have a doubt about how to do something with promises - think about the synchronous version.

```
try{
   var result = myFn(param);
   // business logic with result
} catch(e) {
    //error handling logic
}
```

This, at least to me looks a lot cleaner than a callback with a first parameter that is sometimes `null`.

The promises way is almost always very similar to the synchronous version of the problem:

```
myFn(param).then(function(result){
    // business logic with result
}).catch(function(e){
    //error handling logic
});
```

Where myFn would look something like when working with callbacks:

```
var myFn = function(param){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var calc = doSomeCalculation(param);
        if(calc === null) { // or some other way to detect error
            reject(new Error("error with calculation"), null);
        }
        someAsyncOp(calcN,function(err, finalResult){
            if(err) reject(err);
            resolve(finalResult);
        })
    });
};
```

#### Working with callbacks/nodebacks

This is only something you should have to do when working with callbacks, when working with promises it is a lot simpler, and you can do:

```
var myFn = function(param){
    var calc = doSomeCalculation(param);
    ...
    return someAsyncOp(calcN); // returning a promise.
}
```

Moreover, when working inside promise chains, you get throw safety:

```
myFn(param).then(function(calcN){
   // here, you throw to raise an error and return to resolve
   // new Promise should be used only when starting a chain.
}).catch(function(err){
    // handle error
}).then(function(){
   // ready to go again, we're out of the catch
});
```

---

Note, some libraries like [**Bluebird**](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) , [**RSVP**](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js) and [**Q**](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) offer syntactic sugar and automatic promisification of methods so you rarely have to use `new Promise` yourself.

Also, consider reading [this](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/51) and [that](http://spion.github.io/posts/why-i-am-switching-to-promises.html) to learn more about promise error handling.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the async/await syntax, you can just use the regular try-catch syntax for error handling.

```
// your promise function
const myFn = function(param){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      if (someLogic()) {
          resolve(someValue);
      } else {
          reject('failure reason');
      }
  });
}

// Define the parent function as an async function
async function outerFn(param) {
    try {
        // Wait for the promise to complete using await
        const result = await myFn(param)
        // business logic with result
    } catch (e) {
        //error handling logic
    }
}
```