# How do I handle exceptions globally with native promises in node.js?

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

I know how to [handle specific errors in promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800010/how-do-i-handle-errors-with-promises) but I sometimes have pieces of code that looks like this:

```
somePromise.then(function(response){
    otherAPI(JSON.parse(response));
});
```

Sometimes, I get invalid JSON which causes a silent failure here when `JSON.parse` `throw`s. In general I have to remember to add a `.catch` handler to every single promise in my code and when I don't I have no way to find out where I forgot one.

How do I find these suppressed errors in my code?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Edit

We've finally fixed this in Node.js 15, it took 5 years but native promise rejections now behave like uncaught exceptions - so it's fine to just add a `process.on('uncaughtException'` handler.

### In Modern Node.js

Starting with io.js 1.4 and Node 4.0.0 you can use the `process` `"unhandledRejection"` event:

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", function(reason, p){
    console.log("Unhandled", reason, p); // log all your errors, "unsuppressing" them.
    throw reason; // optional, in case you want to treat these as errors
});
```

This puts an end to unhandled rejections problems and the difficulty of tracking them down in your code.

### In Older NodeJS

These events were not yet back-ported to older versions of NodeJS and are unlikely to be. You can use a promise library that extends the native promise API such as [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) which will fire the same events as there are in modern versions.

---

It's also worth mentioning that there are several userland promise libraries that offer the unhandled rejection detection facilities and much more such as [bluebird](/questions/tagged/bluebird) (which also has warnings) and [when](/questions/tagged/when).