# after adding a listener to a Promise, should I use the original promise or the new one?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have some javasript code that takes an existing promise
(say, the promise returned by fetch()) and adds value
(say, then/catch listeners for debugging, or maybe more):

```
let myFetch = function(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(function(value) {
    console.log("fetch succeeded: value=",value);
    return value;
  }.catch(function(reason) {
    console.log("fetch failed: reason=",reason);
    throw reason;
  });
};
```

I found myself modifying the above code so that the listeners are added only if some condition is true:

```
let myFetch = function(url) {
  let promise = fetch(url);
  if (some condition) {
    promise = promise.then(function(value) {
      console.log("fetch succeeded: value=",value);
      return value;
    }.catch(function(reason) {
      console.log("fetch failed: reason=",reason);
      throw reason;
    });
  }
  return promise;
};
```

Now I'm wondering, does it really make sense for myFetch to return the new promise returned by "then" 
(actually catch which is shorthand for another "then") as above,
or would it make more sense for it to return the original promise (with the added listeners)?
In other words, I'm thinking of leaving out the second "promise =",
so that the code will look like this instead:

```
let myFetch = function(url) {
  let promise = fetch(url);
  if (some condition) {
    promise.then(function(value) {
      console.log("fetch succeeded: value=",value);
      return value;
    }.catch(function(reason) {
      console.log("fetch failed: reason=",reason);
      throw reason;
    });
  }
  return promise;
};
```

Is that effectively different from the previous version?
Is either version preferable, and if so, why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I fire and forget a promise?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32384449/1048572) (which uses async/await, but the problem is the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only use case is logging something in `then`/`catch` – it shouldn't matter as long as everything goes well. Things get more messed if you get an exception. Consider these two examples:

## Return original promise

```
function myFetch() {
    let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(100);
    });
    promise.then(function () { throw new Error('x'); });
    return promise;
}

myFetch().then(function () {
    console.log('success!');
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.error('error!', e)
});
```

The result is `success` and the error thrown in the inner `then` might get  swallowed in some promise libraries (although the most popular ones such as Bluebird handle this and you get additional error `Unhandled rejection Error: x`).
The error might also get swallowed when using [native Promises in some environments](http://jamesknelson.com/are-es6-promises-swallowing-your-errors/).

## Returning modified promise

```
function myFetch() {
    let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(100);
    });
    promise = promise.then(function () { throw new Error('x'); });
    return promise;
}

myFetch().then(function () {
    console.log('success!');
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.error('error!', e)
});
```

Now the result is `error! Error: x`.

Comment: In this case OP was forwarding success/fail correctly in both cases and the only function that they used never throws though. Nice seeing you around again by the way :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Well... it throws if I did something stupid like calling console.warning() when I meant console.warn(), not that I would ever do that ;-)  In general, the possibility of a throw situation that I didn't anticipate, like this, makes me think maybe it's better to use the "Returning modified promise" version so unexpected things don't get swallowed; what do you think?

Comment: That with any decent library unexpected things don't get swallowed anyway - including but not limited to native promises (with the unhandledRejection event), bluebird, Q and other libraries.

Comment: Ah, you're right!  I thought native promises would swallow it, but I just tried it and got an "Uncaught (in promise)" error message, like you predicted, if I'm reading correctly.   So, Michal's answer could be improved if it noted that native exceptions (and Q and other libraries) don't swallow the errors either.  So that clinches it for me in favor of "Return original promise", at least for pure listeners, since it's nice and concise and has no apparent downside.

Comment: I was reading this: http://jamesknelson.com/are-es6-promises-swallowing-your-errors/ and I became less sure of the situation with native promises; however my impression is that native promises shouldn't swallow errors any more, and if any implementations still do it's just a bug that will be fixed, or an illusion due to garbage collection delay.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if your success handler `return`s the value and your rejection handler `throw`s the error - then it is basically the identity transformation for the promise.

Not only do you not need to do that `promise = promise.then` you don't even need to return the values:

```
let myFetch = function(url) {
  let promise = fetch(url);
  if (some condition) {
    promise.then(function(value) {
      console.log("fetch succeeded: value=",value);
    }.catch(function(reason) {
      console.log("fetch failed: reason=",reason);
    });
  }
  return promise;
};
```

That said, if you're using ES6 and let, you can use arrow functions which makes this a little nicer anyway:

```
let myFetch = function(url) {
  let promise = fetch(url);
  if (some condition) {
    promise.then(value => console.log("fetch succeeded: value=",value))
          .catch(reason => console.log("fetch failed: reason=",reason));
  }
  return promise;
};
```

Some promise libraries like bluebird provide a tap utility for this. The only problem is that if ever `fetch` adds support for promise cancellation, you are breaking the chain with the `if (some condition)` handler if you're not chaining it.

Answer (score 1):

You're *promise branching*. In the second case, you're effectively branching the promise chain into two promise chains, because once a caller calls `myFetch`:

```
myFetch("localhost").then(request => { /* use request */ } );
```

then `promise` will have had `.then` called on it twice (once inside `myFetch` to do the console logging, and again here).

This is fine. You can call `.then` on the same promise as many times as you like, and the functions will execute together in the same order whenever `promise` resolves.

But, importantly, each function represents a branch off of the original promise, independent of every other branch. This is why you don't need to return or rethrow anything after your `console.log`: Nobody's listening on that branch, specifically, the caller of `myFetch` is not affected.

This is a good fit for logging IMHO, but there are subtle timing and error handling differences to be aware of when doing anything more:

```js
var log = msg => div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>";

var myFetch = url => {
  var p = Promise.resolve({});
  p.then(() => log("a")).then(() => log("b"));
  return p;
}

myFetch().then(() => log("1")).then(() => log("2")).catch(log); // a,1,b,2
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

This emits `a,1,b,2`. As you can see, there are two chains going on here, advancing in parallel. It makes sense when you think about when `promise` is resolved, but it can be surprising.

The other subtlety is that error handling is also per branch (one branch will never fail another). In fact, the above code has a bug. Did you spot it? There should be a `catch` after `.then(() => log("b"))`, or errors about anything you do in that branch end up unhandled or swallowed in some environments.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and the excellent subtle example to think about.  Had to choose between a couple of good answers.