# Unhandled promise rejection from promise called within Try

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a promise function called `findProperty` which in this case rejects like this:

```
reject('ERR: Unknown propertyID or inactive property in call of newBooking');
```

And this is my handler that calls `findProperty`:

```
async function main() {
    var res = "";
    try { 

        findProperty();
        res = await findUser(userEmail);
        res = await findUser(agentEmail);
        res = await getUsers();

    }
    catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        console.log(" newBooking: " + err);
        callback( { error:true, err } );
    }
}
main();
```

This causes the following error:

```
(node:10276) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ERR: Unknown propertyID or inactive property in call of newBooking
(node:10276) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I dont get this, I got my `catch(err)` shouldn't that be enough?

Just tried something, this works fine:

```
   resolve('ERR: Unknown propertyID or inactive property in call of newBooking');
```

But this gives the error:

```
  reject('ERR: Unknown propertyID or inactive property in call of newBooking');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `findProperty` returns a promise, you need to `await` it in order to trigger the failure within the context of the async function; otherwise the rejection disappears into outer space.

To "fire and forget" without waiting, yet catch failures with your `try/catch`:

```
findProperty().catch(e => { throw e; });
```

Comment: So you cannot use normal promises where you dont want to wait for a reply? I thought you could just mix and match.

Comment: Actually you were right @torazaburo - once I put `res = await findProperty();` it worked just fine.  My question is then, how to I run all my fire and forget promises?  I have a lot where I do not want to wait for a result.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard yes. But then you need to provide a catch like findProperty().catch(console.log.bind(console)); or simply dont reject them

Comment: @Jonasw ahhhh...  okieee.. I think I got it.  So I give them a separate catch so I can print on console or what ever. Didnt know that you could do this, thanks.  What is `console.log.bind`?  Never seen bind before?

Comment: @torbenrudgaard passing console.log just passes *log* , if you do that it will say *error, log isnt part of a console instance* , thats why you need to bind console to it. Or you do:  .catch(e=>console.log(e)); that does not pass a reference so theres no problem...

Comment: @torbenrudgaard See [Can I fire and forget a promise in nodejs (ES7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384449/1048572)

Comment: @Jonas actually in modern engines `.catch(console.log)` works just fine.

Comment: @Jonasw thanks - and Bergi is the promise MASTER :-)