# handle promise error first level inside try catch

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

```
function testPromise(id) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (typeof id === 'number') {
                resolve(id);
            } else {
                reject('error');
            }
        }, 500);
    }
    );
}
async function test(){
  try{
    testPromise(10)
    for(let i=0 ; i<10000; i++){
      ....
    }
    .
    .
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
}
test();
```

ok consider above code I want to run testPromise function asynchronously so if I use await syntax `testPromise(10)` run first then for loop code run if, I don't use await, `testPromise(10)` run  asynchronously and everything is good up to now, however, if testPromise encounter an error how should I handle it? is there any way to use async-await structure and handle this error inside a try-catch structure?
I know I can use catch function `testPromise(10).catch(err =>{});` to handle error but I want to know is there any way to handle it inside my first level try-catch

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I fire and forget a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384449/1048572)?

Comment: So you don't want the loop to wait, but you want the `try` block to wait for it to finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run it concurrently with your loop and properly handle errors from *both* (which necessarily includes waiting for both), then `Promise.all` is your only choice:

```
async function test() {
  try {
    await Promise.all([
      testPromise(10),
      (async function() {
        for (let i=0; i<10000; i++) {
          …
        }
        …
      }())
    ]);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: it's a good solution, however, I think it makes my code looks ugly :)

Comment: @Daniel.V Best make a separate function declaration for the loop part instead of using an AIIFE. And unfortunately it's the only correct solution :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

You either use `try-catch` along with `await` or you use `catch` on the promise.

You should take into account that the error could be thrown even when your function (`test`) already finished its execution.

See @Bergi's answer for a correct example.

Comment: That might lead to an unhandled promise rejection though. Don't do that.

Comment: If `testPromise(10)` gets rejected *and* an exception is thrown from the loop code so that the `await` is not evaluated, the rejected `promise` is dangling.

Comment: Yes, synchronous code can throw an exception as well.

Comment: The double try/catch appears to be quite pointless now, you'd put the outer one around the `await promise` only then. And notice that [unhandled rejections can still happen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46889290/1048572) when the `promise` rejects while the code in the loop `await`s something else.