# Will an async function inside another function continue running after the function has returned?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Sorry if its a really naive question. I have described the situation as follows. My question is, will `OtherAsyncFunction()` continue and complete its execution if `runThis()` returns prematurely?

```
var a = await runThis(); 

async function runThis(){
   // ... 
   OtherAsyncFunction(); 
   // ... 
   return await someOtherAsyncFunction;  
}
```

Comment: if you don't await OtherAsyncFunction, then yes

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Have a look at [Can I fire and forget a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384449/1048572) for how to fix this

Answer (score 3):

It will still execute `OtherAsyncFunction`, unless you do `await OtherAsyncFunction()`.

> An async function can contain an await expression that pauses the
>   execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's
>   resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and
>   returns the resolved value.
>   See more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Please post a link to the source of your quote