# What might happen if I call `AsyncStorage.setItem` without await in non async function?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, promise

I am using `fetch` method to get some data from the server. Once I get that data, I need to store some of it (access_token to be more precise cause I am using oauth) in `AsyncStorage`. I tried doing just `AsyncStorage.setItem` without await, not how it is shown in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage, and it worked just fine.

I changed it to:

```
fetch ('site/login', POST ...)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(async(responseJson) => {
   if (user.valid)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', responseJson.token);
```

And it works fine too. But I have 2 questions now:

Is my implementation with fetch and async correct?

And what might happen if I don't use await/async in this case?

Sorry, I am kinda new to Promises and Asynchronous methods in Javascript. Thanks!

Comment: the implementation you mentioned above is right. if you don't use await/async in this case, you would get the result of Promise clause.

Comment: piece of advice: read about promises especially about chaining them(.then() may return another Promise or non-Promise result and there is a difference in processing). it would also really help on understanding how `async/await` is working under the hood. p.s. and this will explain better why there is no need in async/await inside of chained `.then` as Jared Smith demonstrates. pps Promises are really fun

Comment: Well if you don't want to wait for something, you can [just fire and forget it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32385430/1048572). But usually your caller might expect that after your function is done the token is saved in the storage, and code that depends on this might break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async/await` is just syntactic sugar over Promises. You're already using Promises, so there's no need to do that. Just return the Promise:

```
fetch ('site/login', POST ...)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  if (user.valid) { // not sure where 'user' came from, but whatever
    return AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', responseJson.token);
  } else {
    throw new Error('Invalid user');
  }
})
.then(_ => { // storage set, don't care about return value
  // do stuff
})
.catch((err) => {
  // handle error, including invalid user
});
```

### Response to question in comments

The above in async/await would look like this:

```
async function foo() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('site/login', POST ...);
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    if (user.valid) {
      return await AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', responseJson.token);
    } else {
      throw new Error('Invalid user');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // deal with errors
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And what if I didn't use Promises? Would it not work then without await?

Comment: @good_evening updated my answer. You have no choice but to use Promises because that's what `fetch`, `response.json()`, etc. return, but you can sugar over them with `async/await`. But it's still Promises under the hood, and `foo` will always return a Promise.