# How to use nested functions using async and await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm doing a admin script in my node backend includes mongo queries/updates and api calls. Im using async and await but it does not work as I want.

```
(async () => {
// connect to mongo (works ok)

 const products = await getProducts(); // Here I have my 10 elements

 await Promise.all(products.map(async (prod) => {
    response = await getProductInfo(prod.id);
  })); // here I call to getProductInfo ten times.

})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

const getProductInfo = async(idProduct) => {

  const response = await rq(optionsProductInfo); //request to API

  await Product.updateOne({ sku: response.sku }, { $set: {
    priority: response.priority,
    price: response.price,
  } });  // update product info
};
```

The problem is that the update in the database is not execute 10 times. Sometimes executed 2, 3, 4 times but never execute for the 10 elements.

Comment: Don't promiscuously mix syntaxes. Use try/catch/async/await **or** .then.catch. I can't even read this. One error I see immediately is that you aren't returning anything from your callback to map, although it looks like you're not doing anything with it? What is all of this?

Comment: Try to change the line where you assign response, as basically it will reassign every time new value. Or maybe you should assign response with result returned from `Promise.all`.

Comment: I got it. That's is not my complete/real code, I "simplify it" for this question

Comment: Don't think in terms of "nesting". There is no "waiting for the return" so there technically isn't any nesting happening. When working with async/await think in terms of delegation. Is it okay to delegate tasks as part of a task that is itself delegated? Of course. Good task management means only doing what you need to do and delegate everything else.

Comment: I think I don't need a response. I need that the getProductInfo() method will be execute for the all products listed.

Comment: If you don't need the response, then why `await` anything? Why even build a promise? Just run `products.forEach(p => getProductInfo(p.id))` in your main code?

Comment: @Gere Please show your actual code, or a minimal example that still exhibits the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: @Mike Never use `forEach` :-) In this case, calling `getProductInfo` without waiting for anything will potentially cause cause unhandled rejections. Make sure to [do something about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32385430/1048572)

Comment: That's a bizarre thing to say, @Bergi =)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you're `await`ing the right thing, and that any function that has an await is itself `async`, and you should be just fine. The following code for example works just fine.

```
const products = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

async function updateRecord(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // using timeout for demonstration purposes
    setTimeout(async() => {
      console.log("pretending I updated", data.id);
      resolve();
    }, 1000 * Math.random());
  });
};

async function getProductInfo(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // again using timeout for demonstration purposes
    setTimeout(async() => {
      console.log("fake-retrieved product info for", id);
      resolve(await updateRecord({ id }));
    }, 1000 * Math.random());
  });
};

Promise.all(products.map(pid => getProductInfo(pid)))
       .then(() => console.log("we're done."));
       .catch(e => console.error("what?", e));
```

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! Even (or especially) if `getProductInfo` is just an example mock. And don't use `async` functions as callbacks to e.g. `setTimeout`.

Comment: It's not, I'm very intentionally not doing any then/catching inside these demonstration promises that are very mcuh placeholders for database API calls, and the same goes for setTimeout: there is nothing wrong with marking the function as async which in this case is strictly necessary for that `await` to even work. I'm all for es-today evangelism, but code that's used as stand-in for real APIs is just code that's used as stand-in for real APIs.

Comment: But you don't even need to `await` anything in those callbacks! The first one is entirely synchronous, and the second one should simply `resolve` the promise with the other promise (which properly forwards rejections).

Comment: But database API calls are not synchronous, and that's what we're simulating with the timeouts: highly artificial asynchronous flow. Feel free to write your own answer with what you feel is better code, of course. More than happy to see your take.

Comment: `setTimeout` is not synchronous, but the callback that you pass to it is. No need to make that `async`.