# void before promise syntax

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, tslint

What is the actual impact of putting `void` before promise?

```
async function doAsyncStuff(){
...
}

function nonAsyncFunction(){
  void doAsyncStuff();
}
```

I couldn't find any official documentation for this, but it must be doing something as it resolves [`no-floating-promises`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-floating-promises/) TSLint error.

Comment: how about documentation for the void operator? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was looking for. Tried to find it in Promise docs, apparently I wasn't looking in the right place.

Comment: yeah, `void` has been a javascript operator since Brendan Eich wore short pants :p

Comment: See also: [Can I fire and forget a promise in nodejs (ES7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384449/1048572)

Comment: I personally prefer `/*await*/ fireAndForget();` cause that is also understood by people that aren't that familiar with JS, it doesn't stop the linter from complaining though

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) is an operator that accepts a value on the Right-Hand Side and evaluates as `undefined`.

It resolves no-floating-promises because it does something (or rather, explicitly nothing) with the promise.

Comment: Oh wow, TIL people were using `void` to suppress the rule. Filed https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4653. Thanks for this @Quentin!

Comment: ^ or, how to render the answer incorrect in one easy step.

Comment: Looks like this behaviour can be had back with some config, at least with typescript-eslint.   See https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-floating-promises