# Are promises guaranteed to be executed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

Suppose we have a simple function called `logData` that handles HTTP requests. Suppose, also, that we have another function called `logIntoDatabase`.

```
async logIntoDatabase(message) { ... }

async logData(request, response) {
    await logIntoDatabase("something happened");
    response("log successful");
}
```

Assume that we don't need to be certain that the data was logged onto the database (we don't need to wait for a response from the database). So we make a little optimization:

```
async logIntoDatabase(message) { ... }

async logData(request, response) {
    logIntoDatabase("something happened");
    response("log successful");
}
```

is it **ABSOLUTLY GUARANTEED** that `logIntoDatabase` is going to execute? (As if we waited it to be completed)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Yes, in the second example `logIntoDatabase` will still be fired.  It's just not going to wait for it to finish before firing `response`.

Comment: Well, the only thing guaranteed there is that `logIntoDatabase` will be called if `logData` is being called. Can there be an error in between the start of `logData` and `logIntoDatabase` call? or even in the `logIntoDatabase` function? Yes.

Comment: @zero298 I'm asking this because in python asyncio that is not the case. So I wanted to know if I could trust the nodejs event loop in this case.

Comment: @MinusFour Assume there is no error (I know, I know, this is impossible, but the crux of the matter is the event loop).

Comment: You don't need to handle the return values of your async functions (be it to regular callbacks or through promise API), just like you don't need to handle the return value of your sync functions. That's up to you.

Comment: But...no guarantee it will resolve. Have to code it accordingly and catch rejected promises

Comment: The function is always executed. The execution is not driven by the promise being awaited. If you want to drop the `await`, you should have a look at [Can I fire and forget a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384449/1048572).

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes (at least state what is wrong with the question), however @Bergi pointed out a possible duplicate. Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are promises guaranteed to be executed?

First off, this is a bit of terminology correctness, but promises don't "execute".  Asynchronous functions execute and they create promises that help you monitor their completion.  You aren't calling a promise here.  You're calling a function that returns you a promise.

> is it ABSOLUTLY GUARANTEED that logIntoDatabase is going to execute?

Yes, if `logData(...)` is called, then `logIntoDatabase()` will always execute as the very first line in that function in both your first and second code examples.

Your method like this:

```
async logData(request, response) {
    await logIntoDatabase("something happened");
    response("log successful");
}
```

is essentially equivalent to this (assuming `logIntoDatabase()` returns a promise and doesn't throw synchronously):

```
logData(request, response) {
    return logIntoDatabase("something happened").then(() => {
        response("log successful");
    });
}
```

As such you can see that the very first line to execute inside `logData()` is your call to `logIntoDatabase()`.

---

A full replacement for the `async` function would be this:

```
logData(request, response) {
    try {
        return Promise.resolve(logIntoDatabase("something happened")).then(() => {
            response("log successful");
        });
    } catch(e) {
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
}
```

This covers other misbehaviors such as `logIntoDatabase()` not returning a promise or throwing synchronously.  But, even in this more complete analogy, you can see that `logIntoDatabase()` is still guaranteed to be called.

---

In your 2nd code example:

```
async logData(request, response) {
    logIntoDatabase("something happened");
    response("log successful");
}
```

You are still guaranteed that `logIntoDatabase()` will be called.  But, this will differ in behavior from your version with `await` in three ways:

1. `response("log successful")` will always be called even if `logIntoDatabase()` rejects.
2. `response("log successful")` will be called BEFORE `logIntoDabase()` finishes it's asynchronous operations.
3. The promise returned from `logData()` will not have any connection to whether `logIntoDatabase()` resolves or rejects.  If neither `logIntoDatabase()` or `resolve("log successful")` throws synchronously, then the promise will be resolved with an `undefined` resolved value.  If either does throw synchronously, then the promise returned from `logData()` will reject with the exception as the reason for the rejection.

So, your second example is analogous to this:

```
logData(request, response) {
    try {
        logIntoDatabase("something happened");
        response("log successful");
        return Promise.resolve();
    } catch(e) {
        return Promise.reject(e);
    }
}
```

And, you can see that `logIntoDatabase()` is still guaranteed to always be called.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer! I will mark it as the accepted answer for the time being. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is certain that `logIntoDatabase` is going to execute as long as the function calling it (`logData`) is also executed.

Note that it will not surely do what you expected it to do: it may throw an error or take a significantly long time to fully execute, although that's an issue related to the content of the function, not if you were to call it `synchronously` or `asynchronously`.

Answer (score 1):

> Script inside promise or asynchronous will always be executed unless
>   your application/server force stop or crash.

You can read this article about how asynchronous work. Script still in stack but not blocking other process.

https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-asynchronous-javascript-the-event-loop-74cd408419ff

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Promises in JavaScript are just like promises in real life, once one is made, it is guaranteed to be kept.

Hope this helps

Comment: Well, promises aren't "called".  They are a notification and monitoring mechanism.  Asynchronous functions are called.  Those functions may return a promise which is used to monitor their completion.

Comment: Just in real like, a promise can be broken (rejected). Also there is no guarantee when a promise would be fulfilled.

Comment: It was just a joke guys.