# DB not updated without await infront of the method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hello I have following piece of code:

```
  async create(data) {
    const document = new this.productModel(data);

    const created = await document.save();

    this.userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(data.user, {
      $push: {
        products: created._id,
      },
    });

    return created;
  }
```

And everything works fine except **this.userModel.findByIdAndUpdate** is not updated if **await** is missing infront of it. Deal is there **I do not care about the result from the update** that's why I'm not using **await** I notice on some other services where await is missing infront of the db call, collection is updated correctly (again result db is not needed in the response that's why await is missing) so I'm wondering what is the behavior, how this works? Thanks a'lot!

Comment: Did you check the MongoDB to see if it's updated or not?

Comment: the first argument to findByIdAndUpdate function is supposed to be the Id correct? does data.user variable contain the Id?

Comment: Even if you don't care about `result` you should care about that the update operation is completed successfully. Otherwise you could miss an exception if this update operation fails for some reason.

Comment: @GabrielLupu yes mongodb was not updated, i was thinking my $push is not working right

Comment: @Bevo yes this is the user id it's fine with await infront of it db is updated

Comment: @Anatoly yes you are right, but let's say i don't care if the operation is success or fail

Comment: @AndonMitev ok, you can pass a callback as the third param and add `console.log` there to see if your update has finished with either a result or an error

Comment: If you remove `await` then you might have an `UncaughtPromiseRejection` error in the future. If you don't want to wait for the function then just put a trailing catch method (`findByIdAndUpdate(...).catch((ex) => console.trace(ex));`)

Comment: @AndonMitev check my answer & let me know if it works for you

Comment: If you don't care about the result from the update, you [should not just omit the `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384449/1048572). (Also, while you may not care about the result, you still seem to care about the update itself, so you *should* `await` it anyway).

Answer (score 3):

From Mongoose [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html), *queries are not promises*.

Mongoose will not execute a query until `then` or `exec` has been called upon it (or writing `await` infront). This is very useful when building complex queries.

So to your question, you can try writing your code like this:

```js
const created = document.save().exec();
```