# typescript awaiting an async function that returns a Promise<void>

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

```
Method() {
    // simulating a method of a third-party library that returns Promise<void>
    return new Promise(() => {
      // some time-consuming operations
    }).then(() => console.log('end'))
  }
```

Do we have to use `await` keyword when calling asynchronous methods that are not returning any data?

```
await this.Method().then(() => console.log('done'))
// or
this.Method().then(() => console.log('done'))
```

for this example is it guaranteed that all operations inside the Method() are completed before console prints "*done*" in both cases (using and not using `await` keyword)?

Comment: Why are you mixing `async` with `new Promise()`? If you `return new Promise(...)`, this will probably do what you expect and you don't need to define `Method` as `async`

Comment: this is an example of methods that returning promise<void> like updating or deleting data in firebase realtime database. using async or returning new promise both are returning promise<void>, my question is do we have to await a method that is returning a promise<void> or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that all operations inside the `Method()` are completed before the `.then()` callback prints "done"

Yes, by the virtue of using the [`.then()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). The `await` keyword doesn't matter here. It does matter when you're doing

```
await this.Method();
console.log('done');
```

(which you [probably should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572)).

> Do we have to use `await` keyword when calling asynchronous methods that are not returning any data?

Yes, because they may still throw an error, and you want to wait for the completion even if you don't care about the return value. See [Can I fire and forget a promise in nodejs (ES7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384449/can-i-fire-and-forget-a-promise-in-nodejs-es7) for more discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do as follows:

```
caller = await this.Method().then(() => console.log('done'))
```

or, if you don't need to use the result

```
caller = this.Method()
```

Comment: so are you sure simple call to this.Method() guarantees that all operations inside the Method() are completed before console prints "done" ?

Comment: 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.ts(1308). so caller  = async() => await ... is correct

Comment: There's never a grantee of anything in programing. You don't need to use an asnyc lambda function to call a method that's already marked as async. Your method in side of Method is async so you don't need to wrap it inside of an async lambda to await it, you can just await it. this assumes that the parent function is asnyc though, and if it's not, you should make it even if this is the only thing you're awaiting. If you don't need to await it because you don't care about the result, then you don't need to await it because it's already async.

Comment: what if I want to execute some code just after completion of that promise?

Comment: Then you would need to await it and use your .then like I showed in my first code example. That's literally how it's designed to work, again this is assuming that your parent function is async.

Comment: glad to hear it, do you mind selecting my answer as the correct one or upvoting it?

Comment: i do if you answer my second question as well. by the way assigning void to caller is not wrong?