# Call multiple async functions in parallel, but continue when one specific async has finished

Tags: ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm calling 4 asynchronous network functions in parallel, but I need to wait on one specific function to finish in order to continue my code.

Currently, here's what I've implemented:

```
async function callAllFuncs () {
    // I need to call the important one as it might be delayed in the Network system if there are already too many requests pending.
    // So having the important one first will be better, and might return faster than if I call it at the end

    const importantPromise = fetch('/a') // No await here, as I don't want to block
    fetch('/b')
    fetch('/c')
    fetch('/d')

    return await importantPromise // Now we wait!
}
```

Is there a better way to do that ?

(Calling all four functions and returning as soon as the important one has finished, regardless of the three others).

---

Calling `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled` doesn't work here because it will wait for all functions to either finish or fail. I don't want to wait for the three others at all, I just want to return as soon as '/a' has finished, regardless of the three others.

Comment: `Is there a better way to do that?` No.

Comment: Is there a problem with the code? If this is working code that you want reviewed, then ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @StephenCleary Ok, that's clear :D

Comment: @trincot Makes sense! Thank you

Comment: @trincot The question would be off-topic if posted on Code Review. Please take extra care when recommending Code Review in the future.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Could you elaborate why it would be off-topic? From my understanding, the idea is to review if the suggested code above is good or can be improved. Isn't it the aim of "Code Review"?

Comment: @CyrilN. We can't comment on code where all context is stripped away. Please see our [relevant meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652).

Comment: @Peilonrayz, when I suggest Code Review, I am not suggesting the Asker should not follow the guidelines over there. I will keep recommending Code Review for code review.

Comment: See [Can I fire and forget a promise in ES7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384449/1048572) - you should definitely add some error handling to the promises you are not `await`ing. Also the order of the `fetch()` calls is hardly important if you don't `await` them, so I would not use an extra `const importantPromise` but just call `return fetch('/a');` last.