# async operation inside the promise.then; antipattern?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise

After reaching to tons of previous related questions here and on many other sites, I still cannot understand if I am writing an anti-pattern with the following code:

```
function signUp(email: string, password: string): Observable<UserCredential> {
    return from(
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
        (authRes) => {
          createNewUserDocument(authRes);
          return authRes;
        }
      )
    );
}
```

The ***createNewUserDocument*** is an async function. The point is I want to call it after the user signs up, and I want to return an Observable<UserData> not Observable<Promise<UserData>> (nor Promise<UserData>), hence I cannot make the ***signup*** function async and just use 2 await calls sequentially.

Also, should I put async before then's handler and await before the createNewUserDocument call, or is it not necessary? (code seems to work as it is)

Comment: Well, antipattern or not, it *doesn't work* if your intention was to wait for `createNewUserDocument` as well. Also you're not handling errors from it.

Comment: [Yes, you probably should handle errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384449/1048572).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, antipattern or not, it *doesn't work* if your intention was to wait for `createNewUserDocument` as well. Also you're not handling errors from it.

> Should I put `async` before `then`'s handler and `await` before the `createNewUserDocument` call

Yes, that would work. However, [mixing `async`/`await` with `then` is weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54387912/1048572). If you want to use `await` already, use it in place of every `then` call where possible:

```
function signUp(email: string, password: string): Observable<UserCredential> {
  async function create() {
    const authRes = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    await createNewUserDocument(authRes);
    return authRes;
  }
  return from(create());
}
```

If you wanted to use only `.then()`, chaining still works:

```
function signUp(email: string, password: string): Observable<UserCredential> {
  return from(
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(authRes => {
      return createNewUserDocument(authRes).then(() => {
        return authRes;
      });
    })
  );
}
```

The inner `.then()` might not even be necessary if `createNewUserDocument` returns a promise for the `authRes`.

Comment: this is nice and clean, i will use this. many thanks!