# should I add .then() after the async function call even when i don't need anything back from that function?

Tags: javascript, promise

Let's say I have two async functions.

```
const functionTwo = async () => {
    //do something
}

const functionOne = async () => {
    try { 
        //do something
        functionTwo();
        //do something else
    } catch (e) {
        handleError(e)
    }
}
```

I dont want `functionOne()` to wait for `functionTwo()` to finish its execution so I didn't put `await` infront of `functionTwo()`.
I'm using WebStorm IDE and its showing a warning that I should either put `await` or add `.then()` to `functionTwo()` call. Is it the right thing to do to put `.then()`, even when i don't need to do anything in it?

Comment: Feel free to ignore it if you really don't need it, and if errors will be properly caught. *Usually* it's a mistake, which is why there's a warning - but there are exceptions.

Comment: You're right, no need to put an `await` or a `.then()`. Moreover, if you're not doing any async work in `functionOne` or you don't need to wait for it to get done, you can even remove the `async` keyword for `functionOne`

Comment: @Shreshth functionTwo() itself has some async function calls, so it definitely needs to be ```async```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384449/can-i-fire-and-forget-a-promise-in-nodejs