# Do I need to use await on a function that itself uses await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I've ran into an odd issue in Playwright (an Automation test library) and I have a basic function like this in my page object classes:

```
async open() {
    await super.open("some/url/here");
  }
```

(The base class is basically just a:

```
async open(path: string) {
    await this.page.goto(path);
  }
```

That being said I was mistakenly calling just `someInstance.open()` instead of `await someInstance.open()`

Adding the `await` did fix the issue I was having. However it made me question whether I really needed the `await` within the test if I already have an `await` on the only command in the function?

So is an `await` needed in both places?

Thanks!

Comment: You need await if you need to wait for the promise to resolve/reject.

Comment: If you want _the caller of `someInstance.open()`_ to wait until it's done before continuing with other stuff, then yes, you need it. If you're happy with `someInstance.open()` to finish _sometime later_ and you want to do other stuff in the meantime ("fire and forget"), then no…

Comment: If you don't `await` in the body of the async method, then `await`ing the method call does nothing useful. The execution would finish before the inner call finishes.

Comment: You don't necessarily *have to* await an asynchronous operation.  (If it was required that `async` functions must *always* be awaited then the language would probably just include that internally and not even need the `await` keyword.)  But if you want to await it then you'd `await` it.  It sounds like you may just have a scenario where you may not need to await an operation.  (Sometimes referred to as "fire and forget".)

Comment: @David But they said that adding `await` fixed their problem, so it's *not* a fire and forget scenario.

Comment: **So is an await needed in both places?** Obviously it is, since adding it fixed your issue.

Comment: @Barmar: Ah, for reasons unknown to me I parsed it backwards.  In which case the question is a bit weird... Not awaiting the operation was a problem, awaiting it fixed the problem, and the OP is asking if awaiting it is necessary?  Perhaps the OP could clarify, because overall this seems pretty tautological...

Comment: @David I think they're actually wondering "Why is it needed?"

Comment: I think maybe the question is not being understood. I am asking if you need to `await` the method itself IF the only statement in the method is already being `await`'d

Comment: *If* you want to await the method that awaits the function call, then yes! The `await` isn't needed for the task to complete or something, it's needed if you want to coordinate who waits for whom in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's needed in both places. `open` needs to wait for `goto()` to complete, and the caller needs to wait for `open()` to complete. Otherwise it would be a [fire-and-forget call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384449/1048572): regardless which `await` you omit, the caller of `open` would no longer be waiting for `goto()` to complete.

You can however simplify the functions to just

```
open() {
    return super.open("some/url/here");
}
```

and

```
open(path: string) {
    return this.page.goto(path);
}
```

where you return the promise directly, so that `await someInstance.open()` would still wait for the `goto()` to complete.