# How to deal with dangling promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, es6-promise

Oftentimes I want to call a promise and just let it run asynchronously instead of waiting for it. Like:

```
... some code ...

fetchMyCount().then(count => {
  updateTheUI(count);
});

... more code ...
```

Now this works great, but oftentimes I don't put a failure handler on the promise because that is pretty onerous for each one. That would be like putting a `try {} catch {}` on every one of my data fetches.

The problem is, if it fails, it does so silently. It doesn't throw an exception that my `window.onerror` can get, it doesn't log, it doesn't do anything.

Now I can make a nice wrapper like:

```
Async(fetchMycount().then(count => {
  updateTheUI(count);
}));
```

which can generically deal with promises, but then I have to remember to wrap each and every async call.

Is there a way to have a top-level handler like `window.onerror` or a big `try {} catch {}` wrapper that can catch all un-dealt-with rejected promises so I can log them and make sure they get fixed?

Comment: Can you decorate the promise function?

Comment: You are confusing rejections with errors. The two are not the same. A promise is just a way to resolve a value, and a rejection means that it couldn't be resolved. While I understand you'd like to catch all the rejections, because promises are chainable I don't think it's possible. It's like a function trying to know if the caller uses the return value or not.

Comment: You have to specify a rejection handler to handle rejected promises. There's no way around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common use case. Your problem is real. In Node, you have [`process.on("unhandledRejection", ...`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_unhandledrejection) events which [you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28709666/how-do-i-handle-exceptions-globally-with-native-promises-in-io-js-node-js?rq=1). Sadly, these are not available in browsers yet. Some [libraries](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) which are compatible with ES2015 promises [offer them](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#global-rejection-events) and you can use those until native promises get support.

The upside is that [support in browsers is coming](https://github.com/domenic/unhandled-rejections-browser-spec) and browsers will eventually support these hooks.

Currently, I've convinced [the polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/106) to add it, so if you're using the core-js polyfill you can do:

```
window.onunhandledrejection = function(e){
    // handle here e.promise e.reason
};
```

Note that this assumes that something is an unhandled rejection if: It's unhandled, and an error handler was not attached synchronously (within a task to be precise).

Answer (score 1):

Exactly for issues like this, I wrote my own utility for writing asynchronous code:

https://github.com/vacuumlabs/yacol/

It does not help you with your existing code, however with newly written code it provides (among many other things) quite advanced error-handling capabilities.

This said, I don't think that "unhandledRejection" / "uncaughtException" events are good (although it's the best node.js natively provides) tools to do proper error handling:

- First, you can only attach it process-wide, so it forces you to handle all uncaught errors the same way (unlike with try-catch where you can react differently to errors that originate from different parts of your code)
- Second, "unhandledRejection" is called if .catch is not attached to the Promise in the same run of event loop. This may result in false errors being caught; note it is pretty OK to attach error handler to the promise later!