# How to catch error from promise (node js)

Tags: node.js

```
let commandPromise = async (command) => {
    try {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                child_process.exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                    if (error) return reject(error);
                    if (stderr) return reject(stderr);
                    return resolve(stdout)
                })
            } catch (err) {
                return reject(err)
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
};
```

Is it the correct way to catch the error in this case or exist better way? The code seems not good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I handle errors with promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800010/how-do-i-handle-errors-with-promises)

Answer (score 2):

For your case everithing will work if you add 'await' before new Promise()

```
 let commandPromise = async (command) => {
   try {
       return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           try {
               child_process.exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                   if (error) return reject(error);
                   if (stderr) return reject(stderr);
                   return resolve(stdout)
               })
           } catch (err) {
               return reject(err)
           }
       })
   } catch (err) {
       throw err
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing concepts here but, this is the golden rule:

- For sync code, use try / catch
- For async code, avoid try / catch because doesn't work and go for callback(err, data) or Promise reject styl
- If you are using new ES7 syntax await/sync then you can use try / catch

On your code, this is one simple approach:

```
const commandPromise = async (command) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    child_process.exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          return reject(error);
        }

        if (stderr) {
          return reject(stderr);
        }

        return resolve(stdout)
    });
  });
};
```

ES7 way:

```
const commandPromise = async function(command) {  
  child_process.exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }

      if (stderr) {
        throw stderr;
      }

      return stdout;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of the `try - catch` blocks are unnecessary and you can get rid of them.

Moreover, because `commandPromise` does not use `await` keyword, you can also remove the `async` keyword from the function declaration.

Any errors occured during the execution of the `child_process` would be passed as `error` in the callback which your code already handles.

Here is the better code:

```
let commandPromise = (command) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        child_process.exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            if (stderr) return reject(stderr);
            return resolve(stdout);
        });
    });
```

And to use it:

```
commandPromise(/* some command */)
    .then(() => {
        /* ok */
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        /* handle error */
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors thrown or rejected in promises can be caught by [.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) method. Try/catch doesn't work with asynchronous code.

You can use it like:

```
promise.catch(function(err) {
    // do something
})
```

For more details, look at other [stackoverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21800011/2751596) which target the same question.