# Typescript nested function wrapping Return type problem

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am calling the below function which returns me `Promise<boolean>`

```
const fnc = (i:number) : Promise<boolean>  => Promise.resolve(true)

// Promise<boolean>
const res1 = errorHandler(errorPredicates.sdkError1, fnc, null, 4);
```

However, when I nest it with another error handler the returned object changes to `Promise<any>`

```
// Promise<any>
const res2 = errorHandler(errorPredicates.sdkError1, errorHandler, null, errorPredicates.sdkError2, fnc, null, 4);
```

Below is the example typescript code which reproduces the issue. I am not sure what is wrong here or if it is a limitation of typescript. How can I fix this typing issue?

```
type PromiseFn = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>;
type UnwrappedReturnType<T extends PromiseFn> = T extends (...args: any) => Promise<infer R> ? R : any

type ThrottlerPredicate = (err: any) => boolean;

type ThrottlerPredicates = {
    sdkError1: ThrottlerPredicate
    sdkError2: ThrottlerPredicate
}

const errorPredicates: ThrottlerPredicates = {
    sdkError1: (err) => err?.message?.search(`429:`) != -1,
    sdkError2: (err) => err?.message?.search(`Request was throttled.`) != -1
}

async function errorHandler<ApiFn extends PromiseFn>(
    predicate: ThrottlerPredicate,
    promiseFunction: ApiFn,
    thisArg: ThisParameterType<ApiFn>,
    ...args: Parameters<ApiFn>
): Promise<UnwrappedReturnType<ApiFn>> {
    let errCount = 0
    do {
        try {
            const promiseResult = await promiseFunction.call(thisArg, ...args)
            return promiseResult
        } catch (err: any) {
            //console.error(err)
            if (predicate(err)) {
                if (errCount < 20)
                    ++errCount;
                var ms = 1500 * errCount
            } else
                throw (err);
        }
    }
    while (true);
}

const fnc = (i:number) : Promise<boolean>  => Promise.resolve(true)

// Promise<boolean>
const res1 = errorHandler(errorPredicates.sdkError1, fnc, null, 4);

// Promise<any>
const res2 = errorHandler(errorPredicates.sdkError1, errorHandler, null, errorPredicates.sdkError2, fnc, null, 4);
```

Comment: hi, perhaps have the promise reject with the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800010/how-do-i-handle-errors-with-promises

Comment: I think I am lost about what you are trying to point out. can you please expand your suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the return type is `Promise<any>` is that the generic of Typecript expects the type based on the parameters entered. Therefore, the return type of `PromiseFunction` in `res2` is `Promise<UnwrappedReturnType<ApiFn>`. The `UnwrappedReturnType` type expects the `PromiseFn` type return value. At this time, the `ApiFn` type is an extends of `PromiseFn`, and the `PromiseFn` type's return value is `Promise<any>`, so the `UnwrappedReturnType<ApiFn>` type is `any`.
Again, the `errorHandler` generic `ApiFn` type used as a parameter is the same as `PromiseFn`((...args: any[]) => Promise<any>) type because there are no parameters expected.

In other words, if you specify the `ApiFn` generic type, `res2` type inference is possible.

```
...
type ErrorHandler<ApiFn extends PromiseFn> = (
  predicate: ThrottlerPredicate,
  promiseFunction: ApiFn,
  thisArg: ThisParameterType<ApiFn>,
  ...args: Parameters<ApiFn>
) => Promise<UnwrappedReturnType<ApiFn>>;

// Promise<boolean>
const res2 = errorHandler(errorPredicates.sdkError1, errorHandler as ErrorHandler<typeof fnc>, null, errorPredicates.sdkError2, fnc, null, 4);
```

Unfortunately, I didn't understand the function you wanted, so I answered based on your question. If you can explain the logic to me, I'll think about a better way.